# A continuous, injective function $f:R→R$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis

I saw this answer on this website in response to this question:

A continuous, injective function  $f:R→R$  is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

> Consider $g\colon \{(x,y)\mid x<y\}\mapsto\mathbb R$, defined by
>   $g(x,y):=f(x)-f(y)$. Clearly $g$ is continuous.  Since the domain of
>   $g$ is connected and $g$ has no zeroes, the image of $g$ is an
>   interval not containing $0$.

I can see $g$ is continuous. I can see why domain is connected. I can also see why $g$ has no zeros.

And since continuous image of a connected set is connected, image of $g$ is a connected set. Now connected set in $\mathbb{R}$ is either interval or singleton(not possible).

So image of $g$ is an interval not containing zero.

But, how can I conclude that $f$ is monotonic?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the image of $g$ is an interval that excludes $0$, what can you deduce about $g$?

Comment: @xbh $g$ lies either in the positive half or negative half. So  if it lies in positive half then $f(x)-f(y)=k$ for some positive number, so $f$ is increasing and if it lies on negative half $f$ is decreasing. Am I right?

Comment: Almost. $g<0 \iff f(x)< f(y) \implies f$ is **increasing**.